# How can we give select option in a javascript function table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I created a table using javascript function as show below.

[image]

When I click on `Add Row` then the javascript function gets activated and it creates rows of textboxes.
And the code is

```
function addRow() {    
                        var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); //html table
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length; //no. of rows in table
                        var columnCount =  table.rows[0].cells.length; //no. of columns in table          
                        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); //insert a row            

                        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //create a new cell           
                        var element1 = document.createElement("input"); //create a new element           
                        element1.type = "checkbox"; //set the element type 
                        element1.setAttribute('id', 'newCheckbox'); //set the id attribute   
                        element1.setAttribute('checked',true); //set checkbox by default checked  
                        cell1.appendChild(element1); //append element to cell

                        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);            
                        var element2 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element2.type = "text"; 
                        element2.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element2.setAttribute('name', 'sl'+rowCount);
                        element2.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
                        cell2.appendChild(element2);      

                        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);            
                        var element3 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element3.type = "textarea"; 
                        element3.setAttribute('rows', '4');
                        element3.setAttribute('cols','40');
                        element3.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element3.setAttribute('name', 'discription'+rowCount);
                        cell3.appendChild(element3);         

                        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);            
                        var element4 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element4.type = "text"; 
                        element4.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element4.setAttribute('name', 'quantity'+rowCount);
                        cell4.appendChild(element4);


                        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);            
                        var element5 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element5.type = "text"; 
                        element5.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element5.setAttribute('name', 'price'+rowCount);
                        cell5.appendChild(element5);



                        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);            
                        var element6 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element6.type = "text"; 
                        element6.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element6.setAttribute('name', 'CST'+rowCount);
                        element6.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
                        cell6.appendChild(element6);




                        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6); //create a new cell           
                        var element7 = document.createElement('option'); //create a new element           

                        element7.setAttribute('id', 'vat5'); //set the id attribute 
                        element7.setAttribute('name','tax'+rowCount);
                        element7.setAttribute('value','vat5');
                        cell7.appendChild(element7);
}
```

I am able to create `TextBox`easily but I am not able to get `select(option)` tags inside the `VAT5.5`. So I need to know that how can I create a `select tag` so that when I click on `Add Row` a row should be created with `TextBoxes`and `select tag` in `VAT5.5`.Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you work way too hard.  you can copy the row above and change the id attr.

Comment: Before you createElement 'option', you have to createElement 'select'.

Comment: how are you getting the option value and text ?

Comment: I means you want to display some value in the select tag but from where you want to get this value, like from database ? or from something else ?

Comment: @KalpeshRajai Its from database(writing a query and fetching the data and showing in select of javascript function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code,you need to create and append `select` tag. `option` tags are child elements of select.so instead of creating options,first create a select then add your options to it and select the option you want.
select tag creation should look likes this:

```
var element7 =  document.createElement("select");
  var optarr =  ['vat1','vat2','vat3','vat4','vat5','vat6'];
  for(var i = 0;i<optarr.length;i++)
  { 
   var opt = document.createElement("option");
   opt.text = optarr[i];
   opt.value = optarr[i];
   opt.className = optarr[i];
   element7.appendChild(opt);
 } 
 element7.setAttribute('id', 'vat5'); //set the id attribute 
 element7.setAttribute('name','tax'+rowCount);
 element7.setAttribute('value','vat5');
 cell7.appendChild(element7);
```

**Edit: Enable multi selecting**

if you need to select multiple options you can use `multiple` attribute on select tag like this:

```
var element7 =  document.createElement("select");
element7.setAttribute("multiple","");
```

however by doing this there will be no dropdown anymore,the select element turns to a list box that you can select multiple options from.in order to achieve dropdown with multi select option you need to write it your self or use one of available javascript or jquery plugins like these:

[JQuery Multi Select](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#multiple-select)

[Vue Select](http://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/)

[ParamQuery Select](http://paramquery.com/select)

and many more if you search

Comment: It will throw the `Exception` check your code once again.

Comment: @KalpeshRajai I applied your code and hsh code both are working well.But here i dont want to give the hard-coded options.In the sense the options should be coming from a database table.So How to do it

Comment: @FIFAoneterahertz , replace `var optarr =  ['vat1','vat2','vat3','vat4','vat5','vat6'];` with avalible values of VAT fetched from database and `element7.setAttribute('id', 'vat5');` with `element7.setAttribute('id', VatElementToSelect);`

Comment: @hsh One requirement is there here.I have to select multiple options like vat1 and vat3 at a time.How to do it??

Comment: @FIFAoneterahertz, updated the answer for multi selecting ,hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add the `select` tag with some `option` but you can not created the `select` tag.

so use below code to do that..

```
<div id="addHere"></div>
<script>
    var select=document.createElement("select");
    var op1=document.createElement("option");
    op1.value=1;
    op1.innerHTML="Option 1";

    select.appendChild(op1);

    addHere=document.getElementById("addHere");
    addHere.appendChild(select);
</script>
```

Happy Coding!!!